# Changing LDAP server preference on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, authentication, ldap

I've recently inherited a new environment running Solaris 10 and I was looking for information on how to change the LDAP server preference on an LDAP client, namely through modifying the **NS_LDAP_SERVER_PREF=** variable. I've found only one example of this via Google and that was to utilize the `ldapclient` command in the form of `sudo ldapclient mod -a NS_LDAP_SERVER_PREF=server1,server2,etc`. When using this command however it yields the error " take the form of '-a attrName=attrVal' as described in the
man page: ldapclient(1M)"

Would anybody have some insight as to how to change this variable? I've found the config file where this information is located but it explicitly states that you should *not* edit the file directly but rather use the `ldapclient` command to modify variables.

The reason I am wanting to do this is because there are some servers that are in Germany for example, but they are authenticating through LDAP servers in Canada when we have a local LDAP server in Berlin. I want to change the preference from say **NS_LDAP_SERVER_PREF= quebec-ldap,berlin-ldap** to **NS_LDAP_SERVER_PREF= berlin-ldap,quebec-ldap**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Based off of https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-7511/6mdgu0h2e/index.html what happens if you use preferredServerList instead of NS_LDAP_SERVER_PREF ?